# Can I use alias_method with new a object and give it fixed parameters?

Tags: ruby

Can I do it that way,

But I got some errors about Selenium

```
alias_method :select_by ,Selenium::WebDriver::Support::Select.new(@driver.find_element(:id, "time_entry_activity_id")).select_by


[remote server] file:///var/folders/n5/b8s03z3d7ljg5w74qxm_k4500000gn/T/webdriver-profile20140619-17231-9tb59x/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:9470:7:in `FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_': Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"time_entry_activity_id"} (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError)
    from [remote server] file:///var/folders/n5/b8s03z3d7ljg5w74qxm_k4500000gn/T/webdriver-profile20140619-17231-9tb59x/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:9479:3:in `FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElement'
    from [remote server] file:///var/folders/n5/b8s03z3d7ljg5w74qxm_k4500000gn/T/webdriver-profile20140619-17231-9tb59x/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:11455:11:in `DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h'
    from [remote server] file:///var/folders/n5/b8s03z3d7ljg5w74qxm_k4500000gn/T/webdriver-profile20140619-17231-9tb59x/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:11460:7:in `DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_'
    from [remote server] file:///var/folders/n5/b8s03z3d7ljg5w74qxm_k4500000gn/T/webdriver-profile20140619-17231-9tb59x/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:11402:5:in `DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/<'
    from /Users/hsu-wei-cheng/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:51:in `assert_ok'
    from /Users/hsu-wei-cheng/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.42.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:15:in `initialize'
```

Answer (score 0):

[alias_method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-i-alias_method) accepts only symbols as parameters. Try a different approach.